# How to download mapbox gallery site data?

Tags: dictionary, gist, mapbox

I am trying to make a map of network connections. The MapBox map gallery has some really beautifully laid out maps and I wanted to take the coordinate data to style it for other purposes.

I know this is a long shot, but does anyone know how these maps render data and whether or not the coordinates are accessible after they are made web ready?

i.e. map: http://mapbox.com/tilemill/gallery/#tmcw.rrrr2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this map you're in luck! [@tmcw](http://twitter.com/tmcw) has written about the process of making the map here:

**Article**
http://macwright.org/2011/07/28/mapping-runs.html

**Demo**
http://macwright.org/running

**Code**
https://github.com/tmcw/running